# adding combo box to iphone application

Tags: iphone, combobox

I have found out articles itself but I didn't find any particular solution for this, whether to use tableview or pickerview.

If anyone can explain this with example would be great.

Thanks for all your help!!!

-

Ankita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table views are commonly used and work nicely in interfaces where a drop down list would be used on other platforms.  You can simply add a UITextField above the table view to mimic the functionality of a combo box.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [date cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866) code sample...
it shows how to use the date picker to set the date in a table view cell...
you can use a normal picker view similarly..